# Serial monitor read value depending on delay

Tags: serial

I am working on a small piece of code as shown:
[image]

When I enter character 'a' in the Serial Monitor and use a delay in between successive reads then the monitor gives out acceptable results(i.e 97 for character 'a' and 10 for new line) as shown:
[image]

Whereas if I do not include the delay, it seems like the microcontroller is not able to read the next value(i.e 10 for new line) immediately and just gives out a -1. And it is only after the loop is run again that we get to see the value 10 for new line(again with -1).

[image]

Is my observation correct? If yes, what causes this to occur?

EDIT: I am sorry for the improper format of displaying the code. I am adding the code as below:

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {

  // Initialize I2C communications as Master
  Wire.begin();
  // Setup serial monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("I2C Master Demonstration");
}

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available()>0)
  { 
    char c = Serial.read();
    Serial.print((int)c);
    delay(10);            
    char d=Serial.read();  
    Serial.print((int)d);
    Serial.println("Writing data to slave...");  
}
}
```

Comment: please post the code text, not pictures of code ... you have been asked the same thing on your previous post

Comment: Ok i will consider it next time.... I thought that showing it graphically would make it easier to interpret!

Comment: it makes it very difficult to test your code to see if it even compiles

Comment: Are the downvotes just because of improper way of displaying the code? Or because of  the question itself?

Comment: possibly, you still show the pictures of the code ... if you remove the pictures and the downvotes get reversed, then you will have your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, UART is much slower then the CPU and you run it on extremely slow baud rate. The CPU runs many loops before Serial.available() is again more then 0.

From [reference of read() function](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/):

> Returns the first byte of incoming serial data available (or -1 if no data is available).

Comment: But why is  '-1' here? What does it indicate?

Comment: I enhanced the answer

Comment: the -1 works 100% correctly only for `int` data type ... `int c = Serial.read();` ... the reason is that -1 is binary 11111111 as a byte (255 decimal) ... it is 1111111111111111 as an integer ... if you receive a valid `byte` of 255,  your code will see it as meaning `no data` ... if you receive it as an `integer` then your code will see it as data ... int 255 = binary 0000000011111111 .... your code receives bytes (char), so you could get into trouble with char(255)